# Why does Xcode's editor jump upwards whenever I place a Breakpoint?

Tags: xcode, ide

Whenever I place a breakpoint down in Xcode 3.2.1, for whatever reason the editor likes to jump upwards by 100-200+ lines, losing my place in the source code.  This appears to only occur in projects that I've been worked on for a little while, opening/closing them several times.  New projects don't have the issue, but eventually develop it.

Any idea on what's causing this (user error, software glitch), and ideally how to fix it?  Cheers!

Comment: XCode4 still seems to jump occasionally

Comment: I wonder if this is the same bug as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761295/xcode-6-code-editor-erratic-behaviour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a glitch in Xcode 3.x. Perhaps when Xcode 4.x gets released Apple will fix this problem.